# What parameters to open calendar with a link?

Tags: calendar, parameters, commandlink

I have an `<apex:commandLink>` that opens calendar page in a new tab :

```
<apex:commandLink value="Calendar" target="_blank" action="{!showCalendar}"/>
```

In controller, I have :

```
public PageReference showCalendar() {
    PageReference page = new PageReference('/00U/c');
    page.setRedirect(true);
    return page;    
}
```

This code redirects from calendar page.

I would like to know, what are the parameters I can put in URL to :

- select if I show one or several users in calendar,
- select 1-day, 1-week or 1-month for the view,
- select the start day of the period to show.

Where can I find this parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('/00U/c?md0=2015&md1=11');
```

Here **md0** is year and **md1** is month.

**md2** is  week and

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('/00U/c?md0=2015&md2=40');
```

**md3** is  day and

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('/00U/c?md0=2015&md3=330');
```

Note: only month starts with 0.

For **Multi-User Calendar - Day View**

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('/00U/c?cType=2&md0=2015&md3=330');
```

For **Multi-User Calendar - Month View**

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('/00U/c?cType=2&md0=2015&md1=10');
```

For **Multi-User Calendar - Week View**

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('/00U/c?cType=2&md0=2015&md2=44');
```

You need to add **cType=2**

Answer (score 1):

**For month view:**

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('00U/c?cType=1&md0=2015&md1=11');
```

> md1 is month view

**For week view:**

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('00U/c?cType=1&md2=50&md0=2015');
```

> md2 is week number

**For day view:**

```
PageReference page = new PageReference('00U/c?cType=1&md0=2015&md3=341');
```

> md3 is day number